# Why the hate on this HTML/CSS question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am curious to hear the reasoning behind why [Simple Business Card Website](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148349/simple-business-card-website) is still closed.

- It has a title describing what the code does
- It requests a code review
- It contains the code that needs to be reviewed
- The code needing review works as intended
- The code is fully reviewable

Comment: There's 2 lines (one sentence) of explanation and ca. 350 Lines of code ...

Comment: OP hasn't come back to Code Review since Nov 29, so another question is whether it matters. The code wasn't of spectacular quality either, breaking down in some browsers.

Comment: Makes sense! Reopened it now.